# Uploading a CSV in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, csv, phpmyadmin

I am trying to upload a `.csv` file in phpMyAdmin without success.

The first way: Selecting the current database and directly import the zipped file then selecting `CSV` under `Format of imported file` and `,` as delimiter.

I get no error but when the upload is complete nothing happens and the page remains white empty.

Second way: I created a table with the same number of columns (43) included in the csv file. Then import the CSV file using the same configuration as before.

I get an error basically saying that number of fields in the CSV imported is not valid even though it is.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try unzipping it first?

Comment: may be your number contain "separator" like 1,000,000